# how to edit, save fillable pdf in browser with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

Is it possible to edit a pdf in a browser and save as a new pdf file to the server?[image]
This is how i view the pdf file.

```
<object data="<?=base_url()?>html_public/pdf/ri.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="910" height="400">
      <!-- support older browsers -->
      <embed src="<?=base_url()?>html_public/pdf/ri.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="910" height="400"/>
      <!-- For those without native support, no pdf plugin, or no js -->
      <p>It appears you do not have PDF support in this web browser. <a href="<?=base_url()?>html_public/pdf/ri.pdf" target="_blank">Click here to download the document.</a></p>
</object> 
    <div id="submit"><?php $data = array('name' => 'but', 'id' => 'choose', 'value' => 'true', 'type' => 'submit'); echo form_button($data, 'Update' ); ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create the controller
and paste the this
$this->load->view('your view name');
        // Get output html
        `$html = $this->output->get_output();`

```
    // Load library
    `$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');`

    // Convert to PDF
    `$this->dompdf->load_html($html)`;
    `$this->dompdf->render();`
    `$this->dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");`
```